# Can we trigger multiple tests in parallel in pytest but with a little time difference

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-xdist, parallel-tests

I have created a pytest framework where each test triggers a Jenkins job to deploy some application and then perform some validation.
(I am using pytest-jenkins module to trigger a Jenkins build from python)
However, when I run these tests in parallel (using pytest-xdist -n auto), same Jenkins build gets triggered from 2-3 different tests which I don't want.
So, I am looking for some option where tests are run in parallel but are triggered with a time gap of few seconds..
Note - As each test takes about an hour to complete, running them one after other is not good option for me.

As a temporary workaround, I have added some sleep time of 5 sec, 10 sec in each test so that when they are run in parallel, the Jenkins job gets triggered with a time gap..
But I am looking for some better solution.
Thanks in advance!!